# Access and display an image using its index

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

I have a very basic page displaying six images and a textbox asking a user to enter the number of an image they want displayed into a new window.

The idea is to mostly manipulate the page using pure javascript to control the DOM. All jQuery you see is acceptable, but I must access and display the images by indexing into them.

```
function checkInput() {
  var input = document.getElementById('txtNum').value; //get image number to display
  if (input < 1 || input > 6) {
    $('#error').empty().append('!Please enter a number between 1 and 6!');
    return;
  } else {
    $('#error').empty();
    var indexSrc = document.images[input-1].src;
    var newWindow = window.open("", "Image", "height=500", "width=500");
    newWindow.document.write( 
      "<img src='indexSrc' />" //error
    )
  }
}
```

The logic is simple, and it seems to be working correctly besides actually displaying the image in the new window. I'm currently storing the image src into a variable and then trying to display the image using that same variable. I'm assuming this is not acceptable, but haven't been able to find any correct solutions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Change this `"<img src='indexSrc' />"` to `"<img src='" + indexSrc + "' />"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace

```
    "<img src='indexSrc'/>"
```

by

```
    "<img src='" + indexSrc + "'/>"
```

and see if it works.

When you put 'indexSrc' in the string you are not actually referencing the variable indexSrc that you've created.

Comment: credits to @EyeuIDK that also answered the question in the comments section.